# prometheus differentiate alerting

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Please advise how to state in templated or alert rules Prometheus for which nods or services is it. I didn't find info on variables in documentation. For example I have alert rules for backend, MongoDB, for hardware, containers (Dockers) how would Prometheus differentiate where and how apply these alert rules?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's just a matter of how you configure your rules and labels (`prometheus_rules.yml`). Observe what information is in the metric and use the labels for additional info or filtering. Consider the popular metric `up`. Here is how you can create a rule that is taking into account some of the labels. You may use the predefined labels that come from a particular exporter e.g. `up{job="node"}` or assign new ones as in the example below (`service, severity`).

```
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up{job="node"} == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: error
      service: cluster
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes."
```

Comment: Thanks!I cannot understand how Prometheus understands that this alert rules for a web service with this IP: port, but this alert rules for a backend with another IP: port

Comment: and where I define ip: port, which is then used in alert rules templates and for

Comment: I feel that you are referring to `scrape_configs` - this is where you defined the endpoints of `node_exporter` Prometheus will scrape. I am also using jinja templates in my ansible role to make it generic: `{ hostvars[host].ansible_fqdn }}:9100`